# Unity C# Grid Based Building System Not Working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a survival game and I am trying to build a building system similar to Rust.

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SnapToGrid : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject buildingPrefab;

    public float gridDistance = 2f;

    float gridSize;

    Vector3 gridPosition;
    Vector3 worldPosition;

    void Start() {
        worldPosition = transform.position;

        gridSize = 1f / gridDistance;
    }

    void Update() {

        gridSize = 1f / gridDistance;

        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, 0f));

        RaycastHit hit;

        Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit);

        worldPosition = hit.point;

        //Vector3 distanceVec = hit.point - Camera.main.transform.position;
        //worldPosition -= distanceVec.normalized * (distanceVec.magnitude - 1f);

        gridPosition = new Vector3(
        Mathf.Round(worldPosition.x * gridSize) / gridSize,
        Mathf.Round(worldPosition.y * gridSize) / gridSize,
        Mathf.Round(worldPosition.z * gridSize) / gridSize);

        transform.position = gridPosition;

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) {
            Instantiate(buildingPrefab, gridPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
}
```

There is a preview where the raycast from the camera comes in contact with a collider, and whenever you click it will instantiate the building in the place where the preview is.

[Preview of building and placed buildings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCJl5.png)

HOWEVER... The problem I currently have is whever you try to place a building on the side of another building, it clips through and goes inside that building.

[Preview clips into building](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6HuD.png)

This makes it impossible to place one building on the side of another, and it also makes it so you can stack multiple buildings in the exact same position. These are both things I do not want.

Do you guys know of any way to make the preview on the side of the placed building instead of inside it? Thanks, Rugbug.

Comment: you will have to perform some kind of check to see if the position of the returned coordinates is already occupied with another building. you could do that with rigid body and collision detection. another possibility is to make a 2D array that represents your grid where you remember which positions are already occupied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this:

```
Vector3 newPos = hit.point + hit.normal.normalized;
```

And that worked out.